# how to navigate from host activity to fragment using navigation jetpack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I used jetpack navigation to move between fragments
In the activity that I defined as host, there are several views that should be clicked to lead to fragments.
But in drawing graphs, you could only connect the fragment to the fragment, how can you draw an activity graph to the fragment?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a connection between an activity and a fragment. You can simply do this in Kotlin:

**Your Activity**

```
// R.id.nav_host_fragment is your Nav Host Fragment in the activity.xml
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

// Then navigate to one of the fragments in the res/navigation/nav_graph.xml
navController.navigate(R.id.yourFragmentId)
```